# $a$ modulo ${\prod_{i}p_i}$ where $p_i$ are primes.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

This may be a very simple question for many of you. But somehow I can not see how to find a good way to answer this. The question is that if it is given that $$a\equiv k_i\mod{p_i},\quad i=1,2,\cdots,n$$ where $a$ is some integer and $p_i$ are primes. Then what can be said for $k$ where $$a\equiv k\mod{N}$$ where $\displaystyle N=\prod_{i}p_i$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Chinese Remainder Theorem?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)  What do you wish to know about $k$?

Comment: Oh, correct @BillDubuque. Yeah, I once studied Chinese Remainder Theorem, but forgot it. Now as you pointed this out, the answer seems to be pretty clear and question seems to be rather silly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post your solution and then accept it to close the issue.

Comment: @BillDubuque, can you kindly write this as an answer so that I can accept it and then close the issue as suggested by @vonbrand?

Comment: @Samrat Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a special case of the solution of a system of congruences that is encapsulated in the fundamental [Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) which applies in this case since the moduli $\,p_i$ are pairwise coprime, being distinct primes. See the linked Wikipedia article for the basics and please feel free to ask for further elaboration if anything there is not clear. Furthermore, various aspects of CRT are also discussed in [many MSE answers.](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com+%28chinese+remainder+OR+%22CRT%22%29)

[Comment promoted to answer per request]